# Get all User Facebook Friends, not only the ones who have used the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

is there anyway to get all the friends from a user using the graph api?

In christmas I did an app where i used "me/taggable_friends" to retrieve the list and tag those users on a photo, but right now I just want to retrieve the list and then send a message to the user I pick, and this means facebook won't validate my submition because im not tagging anyone...

Is there anyway to get all the friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don´t want to tag users, or invite users to a game with canvas implementation, there is no way to get all users anymore. More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

In order to send messages to a user, just use the Send Dialog instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

You can´t send a message with the API anyway, so it would be pointless to get a list of all users for that.

Comment: maybe i explained myself wrong, i'm using the send dialog, but in the message i send a unique url where only the user that I picked from the list can enter... thats why i need it

Comment: not possible at all to get the list of all users for that, i´m afraid. not tagging and not inviting to a canvas game.